# How should a Formly validation function contribute to error messages?

Tags: angularjs, angular-formly

I have an asynchronous Formly field-validation function that is used in several forms and checks multiple aspects of the field.  I'd like to be able to "return" (in a general sense) error text from the field-validation function that spells out exactly what is wrong with the field.

What is the best way to do that?  I'd guess that I want to emit the text into the scope, but I'm not sure where.  I've dug through all the examples (I think) and don't see anything germane.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do this through a combination of [formlyValidationMessages](http://docs.angular-formly.com/v5.0.3/docs/formlyvalidationmessages) and a fieldWrapper.  The initial configuration is pretty daunting, but results in a pretty flexible validation system that allows you to handle synchronous and asynchronous validation errors the same.  Most of this post was cobbled together from the official [async Validation example](http://angular-formly.com/#/example/other/unique-value-async-validation).

formlyValidationMessages allows you to configure some default error messages for typical validation errors.  Here's an example I use in my projects

```
angular.module('myModule', ['formly']).run(formlyValidationMessages){
    formlyValidationMessages.messages.required = 'to.label + " is required"'
    formlyValidationMessages.messages.max = '"The max value allowed is " + to.max'
    formlyValidationMessages.messages.min = '"The min value allowed is " + to.min'        
}
```

These are [Formly Expressions](http://docs.angular-formly.com/v8.0.0/docs/formly-expressions) so they can be strings or functions.

This basically sets a watch on the fields error property in the angular form.  If it there's an error in the form for the field, (e.g. `form.field.$error.required === true`), it'll add max to validation.messages in your field configuration object.

If you need a specific error for a specific field you can add it to the field definition.  e.g.

```
var field = {
    key: 'serialNumber',
    type: 'input'
    ....
    validation: {
      messages: {
        unique: function() {
          return 'Serial number 123 is not unique'
        }
      }
    }
    asyncValidators: {
      unique: {
          expression: function(modelValue, viewValue, scope) {
            return $timeout(
              function(){
                if(modelValue === '123') {
                  throw 'unique failure: 123'  //throw to reject promise
                }
              },
              1000
            )
          }
      }
    }
}
```

To display this to the user, create a hasError wrapper for your fields that uses [ngMessages](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMessages/directive/ngMessages) to create a per field error list for your fields.

```
module.config(function(formlyConfigProvider) {
  formlyConfigProvider.setWrapper({
    name: 'hasError',
    template: '<div class="form-group" ng-class="{\'has-error\': showError}">' +
      '  <label class="control-label" for="{{id}}">{{to.label}}</label>' +
      '  <formly-transclude></formly-transclude>' +
      '  <div ng-messages="fc.$error" ng-if="showError" class="text-danger">' +
      '    <div ng-message="{{ ::name }}" ng-repeat="(name, message) in ::options.validation.messages" class="message">{{ message(fc.$viewValue)}}</div>' +
      '  </div>' +
      '</div>'
  })
})
```

[Here is a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/LJkQNqWryfvIK0xgcw1z) that has a functioning example using bootstrap styling.  If you input 123, you'll get an asynchronous validation error, but if you leave it blank you'll get a synchronous one.

Comment: I hope you found an answer before now, just wanted to record a way since I stumbled upon this question.

Answer (score 0):

Angular supports the use of custom validation, so for example, you want to check the username for uniqueness, you can create your own directive to do this.

Like this example: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms

You create your directive with the check for uniqueness and check if the directive is triggered and use `ng-show` to only show it when its needed.

`<span ng-show="form.name.$error.username">This username is already taken!</span>`

Comment: This is not an answer to the question, which asked about how to return text from a formly validation function, and requires some formly understanding.